# How to set daily repeating notification in android studio at different times each day?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, push-notification, notifications

I currently have daily repeating notifications which repeat at 6pm each day. What I want to do is instead of 6pm, show the notification when a event is about to start. I have a events arraylist, and it contains dates and times, would this be possible. Below is how I am currently showing the notifications.

This is in my main activity

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
 calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 18);
 calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
 calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
 Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
 PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0,intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
 AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(MainActivity.this.ALARM_SERVICE);
 am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

and this is in my broadcast_reciever class

public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

```
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, EVentsPerform.class);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


        Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                context).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.applogo)
                .setContentTitle("Alarm Fired")
                .setContentText("Events To be PErformed").setSound(alarmSound)
                .setAutoCancel(true).setWhen(when)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000});
        notificationManager.notify(MID, mNotifyBuilder.build());
        MID++;

    }

}
```

I am not sure how to set the time so it repeats when and if there is a event. Any pointers and help with be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can set an alarm for each event. read all the events times from your database and then set individual alarms for those events. Instead of setRepeating use this. The set alarm variant is for different Android versions to wake up the phone from sleep.

```
private void setAlarm(Long dateInMillis) {

    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        am.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, dateInMillis, pi);
    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        am.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, dateInMillis, pi);
    } else {
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, dateInMillis, pi);
    }
}
```

dateInMillis is the `Calender.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()` for the time you want to set the alarm for. So i hope you have a long stored in your database which is that value to make your life easier for this

```
public ArrayList<String> getAlarms() {
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    String myPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;

    db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM TABLE";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        result.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("WhateverYourColumnIs")));
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            result.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("WhateverYourColumnIs")));
        }
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    return result;
}
```

You can convert the string to a Long

```
DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper();
ArrayList<String> alarms = db.getAlarms()

for(String alarm : alarms){
    try{
        setAlarm(Long.parseLong(alarm));
    }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
        //Not a number
    }
}
```

something like that

```
private Long calendarMillis(String date, String time){
    Long result;
    //Do A bunch of stuff to get the information to fill in below from what you bring in.
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    //...Calendar.HOUR, Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.DAY
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    result = c.getTimeInMillis();
    return result;
}

public class NotificationInformation{
    Long alarmTime;
    String name;
    public void NotificationInformation(){

    }
    public void NotificationInformation(NotificationInformation ni){
        this.name = ni.getName();
        this.alarmTime = ni.getAlarmTime();
    }
    //getters and setters
    public void setAlarmTime(Long alarmTime){
        this.alarmTime = alarmTime;
    }
    public void setName(String name){
        this.nime = nime;
    }
    public Long getAlarmTime(){
        return alarmTime;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_PATH = "/data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE_HERE/databases/";
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "YOUR_DATABASE.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase = null;

    private final Context myContext;
    Context context = null;

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.myContext = context;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        myDataBase = this.getWritableDatabase();
        myDataBase.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS INFO (" +
                "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                "alarmTime INTEGER," +
                "name TEXT)");
    }

    public void addInfo(long time, String name) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("alarmTime", time);
        values.put("name", name);

        db.insert("INFO", null, values);
        db.close();
    }

    public ArrayList<NotificationInfo> getInfoAll() {
        String selectQuery;
        SQLiteDatabase db;
        Cursor cursor;
        NotificationInfo ni = new NotificationInfo();

        ArrayList<NotificationInfo> result = new ArrayList<NotificationInfo>();
        String myPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;

        db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM INFO";
        cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            ni.setAlarmTime(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("alarmTime"));
            ni.setName(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
            result.add(new NotificationInfo(ni));
            while(cursor.moveToNext()){
                ni.setAlarmTime(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("alarmTime"));
                ni.setName(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
                result.add(new NotificationInfo(ni));
            }
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        return result;
    }
}

public class AlarmActivity extends Activity{
    //standard code for activity goes here
    private void buttonClicked(){
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        DatabaseHandler db = new Databasehandler(AlarmActivity.this);
        ArrayList<NotificationInfo> alarms = db.getInfoAll();
        db.close();

        for(NotificationInfo ni : alarms){
            c.setTimeInMillis(ni.getAlarmTime());
            c.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -30);
            setAlarm(c);
        }
    }

    private void setAlarm(Long dateInMillis) {
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            am.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, dateInMillis, pi);
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            am.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, dateInMillis, pi);
        } else {
            am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, dateInMillis, pi);
        }
    }       
}

public class NotificationInformation{
    Long alarmTime;
    String name;
    public void NotificationInformation(){

    }
    public void NotificationInformation(NotificationInformation ni){
        this.name = ni.getName();
        this.alarmTime = ni.getAlarmTime();
    }
    //getters and setters
    public void setAlarmTime(Long alarmTime){
        this.alarmTime = alarmTime;
    }
    public void setName(String name){
        this.nime = nime;
    }
    public Long getAlarmTime(){
        return alarmTime;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I see that you are deleted all the comments, I am sorry to bother you again. I asked you previously why did you create the DatabaseHandler class to which you did not respond, may I ask should that be an addition to the sqlite table I already have or represent that? I really appreciate your effort but I am unable to put it all together, if I could give me a little guidance whilst I put the code together hopefully I can get it working.

Comment: i didnt delete the comments. a moderator probably did. i use the database helper class because it implements SQLiteHelper. SQLLiteHelper class is a built in module to handle database operations within the android platform. it is what allows me to do things like db.insert(). Look up [android database example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm)

Comment: Ok so do you create another database that holds the dates and names to be passed for the notifications?

Comment: no why would you do that? I dont believe you have a database at all right now. how do you create a database without a database helper class? show your database code.

Comment: I do have a database in SQLite, so that's why I asked why did you create the DatabaseHandler class as I see you are inputting values into it.

Comment: if you are not using a helper class then i would say your are doing it wrong. let me see your code