# How to set a reminder for events stored in a database android studio?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, events, reminders

I am working on a app that allows users to store list of events in a sqlite database in android studio. I store the date, time and both of these in millis, What I want to do is (if possible) take the the millis I store and set a reminder for 15 minutes before the event is about to occur. I have been able to set a daily repeating notification (which I preset the the time for) and have no idea of where to begin implementing the reminders for each event. Any help will be appreciated.

I have read a post doing the same thing, but cannot make sense of what's been written and not sure if the answer solved the OP problem as no comments are available.

[How to set daily repeating notification in android studio at different times each day?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42120882/how-to-set-daily-repeating-notification-in-android-studio-at-different-times-eac)

Comment: Since you were able to create repeating notifications then what is your problem? Just set time in AlarmManager to fire 15 min before the event, substract 900000 from events miliseconds

Comment: There are several events in the list, how should I go about adding the reminder to all the events?

Comment: You can set alarm for event when you are adding it to database

Answer (score 0):

You should use AlarmManager and PendingIntent;

```
 AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourReceiver.class);


        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, YOUR_REQUEST_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        manager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), timeYouSavedinDB - 150000, pendingIntent);
```